# How to set NoAccel to disable i915 GPU from Xorg.conf (to avoid GPU hang)

Tags: xorg, gpu, i915

I'm running Ubuntu on a new system with a GPU that uses the i915 kernel module. Unfortunately several times a week the gui crashes and dumps me to a terminal. `journalctl` shows the problem is:

```
kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:1:859fddff, in budgie-wm
```

I'm working on diagnosing the problem, but that's not my question today. Today I simply want to disable Xorg from using the GPU at all, so I can use Xorg without crashing. (I tried kernel parameter `nomodeset` which indeed disabled the GPU but then I couldn't even dim the screen backlight, so that's too extreme of a method for me. This is why I'm now looking at the Xorg layer.)

I read from the ArchLinux wiki that sometimes [GPU hanging can be solved](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics) by setting `Option "NoAccel" "True"` in Xorg.conf. That's what I want to try.

There's some missing explanation, however. I think I should add this by creating a file under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-noaccel.conf`. `man xorg.conf` explains that `xorg.conf` is organized into sections. What section should `NoAccel` go in? Maybe it should go in the `Device` section, but does that mean I have to put other lines in the same section to identify the device? And how can I tell whether `NoAccel` is recognized successfully in Xorg?

Comment: I haven't solved this, but for now I greatly reduced the crashing by disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox settings > General > Performance (since Firefox graphics acceleration seems to have triggered most of the crashes).

Answer (score 0):

It is under device section. From [X11R7.7 manpae](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/intel.4.xhtml)

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "devname"
Driver "intel"   
...
EndSection
```

The option is

```
Option "NoAccel" "boolean"
```

```
Disable or enable acceleration.

Default: acceleration is enabled.
```

For some reason [Arch manpage](https://man.archlinux.org/man/intel.4) doesn't mention it. Instead it mention this (which can be found in previous one too)

```
Option "Accel" "boolean"
```

```
Enable or disable acceleration.
Default: acceleration is enabled.
```

Put the configuration in a xorg.conf file. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-disableacc.conf`, put the device section.

Comment: Am I supposed to already have a device section? If so, I can't find it. Can you give a specific step by step, so I can tell you where I get lost? Also, your example mentions `Driver "intel"` but according to `lspci` my driver is i915...does this work for i915?